# Программное изменение цвета кнопки

Tags: android, button, background

пытаюсь программно изменить цвет кнопки:

```
btnAnswer1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteDark));
```

цвет такой описан в ресурсах:

```
<color name="whiteDark">#2D2D2D</color>
```

однако выдает ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
        at example.englishapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:92)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Пытался также изменить цвет кнопки следующим образом:

```
btnAnswer1.setBackgroundColor(btnAnswer1.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteDark));
```

Выдает такую-же ошибку. Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Обычное изменение цвета кнопки при помощи `btnAnswer1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)` и т.п. не устраивает, т.к. нужного мне цвета нет в библиотеке
Также пытался установить фон кнопки при помощи `btnAnswer1.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/btn_top_border"));`
в ресурсах предварительно описан фон:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape> </item> <item android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"> <solid android:color="#2D2D2D"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Код MainActivity:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MY_SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);
    themen = sp.getString("themen", "Night");
    btnAnswer1.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/btn_top_border"));
    if (!hasVisited) {
        writeFile();
        readFile();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstStartActivity.class));
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
        e.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
        e.commit();}
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ct1 = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl1);
    btnSound = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSound);
    btnMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
    tvLearningWords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLearningWords);
    tvTranscription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTranscription);
    setTitle("Новые слова");
    btnAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer1);
    btnAnswer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer2);
    btnAnswer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer3);
    btnAnswer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer4);
    btnAnswer5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer5);
    btnSound.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAnswer1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAnswer2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAnswer3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAnswer4.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAnswer5.setOnClickListener(this);}
```

Comment: У вас `btnAnswer1` - `null`. Наверное вы перепутали ID в разметке.

Comment: Код `MainActivity.onCreate` и разметку покажите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Вы пытаетесь вызвать `btnAnswer1.setBackground` до вызова `setContentView` и `super.OnCreate`.

   Переместите в самое начало метода `onCreate` эти вызовы:

   ```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ```
2. Вы вызываете `btnAnswer1.setBackground` до его инициализации.

   `btnAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer1);` должно быть перед `btnAnswer1.setBackground`

Comment: Немного не пойму, я правильно использую ресурсы drawable? Мне необходимо 
собственный фон на кнопке поставить, который описан в папке res/drawable код его приведён в вопросе. btnAnswer1.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/btn_top_border"));

Comment: @i_burykin ошибка `NullPointerException` в вопросе с фоном никак не связана. Если у вас проблемы с установкой фона, то это лучше отдельным вопросом задать.